# What actually is Boyer-Lindquist coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, definition, kerr-metric

I want to know the difference between spherical and [Boyer-Lindquist coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates). Don't they both use $r, \theta, \phi$ parameters? I've searched books and sources on the internet and there's none that explain what Boyer-Lindquist coordinate is.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Lindquist_coordinates) Note that they relate to Cartesian coordinates in a different way than normal spherical coordinates do.

Comment: In his 2007 paper [The Kerr spacetime: A brief introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622) Matt Visser gives an excellent description of all the coordinate systems commonly used for the Kerr metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same for a=0.
 For a>0 you get eliptical coordinate lines for the distance parameter
 (translate https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Lindquist-Koordinaten). 
Your link is an adaption for Kerr-Newmann metric ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Just to be clear, so does that mean that coordinate system itself, not metric, actually changes according to $a$?

Comment: Sure. Nothing is said about a metric tensor and whether its Rieman Tensor ist zero (flat Euclidian space) or not.

Comment: (charged metal disc of radius a: orange=electric field lines, blue=equipotential surfaces)

Comment: Oh ok, I guess I got it. Thanks a lot.